# как в python tkinter через PhotoImage узнать размер изображения?

Tags: python, tkinter

как мне узнать размер изображения через `PhotoImage`?

мой код:

```
from tkinter import *

win = Tk()

картинки = [PhotoImage(file="C:\питон.gif")]
картинкаimage = Label(win, image=картинки[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего сделать это через модуль Pillow, для начала импортируем его:

```
from PIL import Image as i
```

дальше соответственно получаем размер:

```
im = i.open('C:\питон.gif') 
width, height = im.size #переменные width, height
```